# How to assemble the file using the range header?

Tags: java, http, range

I use range hader, but not create correct file.

if I send `Range bytes=0-8999` file weighs 9000 bytes and correct work.
if I send `Range bytes=0-8999,9000-9999` file weighs 10213 bytes and **NOT** correct work.

File type mp3.

What could be wrong?

```
HttpGet first = new HttpGet("http://cs4832.vkontakte.ru/u50184979/audio/ef64581d913c.mp3");
first.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
first.addHeader("Range", "bytes=0-8999,9000-9999");

//first.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(first, localContext);


InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
File f = new File("outFile1.mp3");

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = instream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
out.close();
instream.close();
```

Comment: `Range bytes=0-8999,9000-9999` - apart from being consecutive, so should be a single range, that's `10,000` bytes.

Comment: I'd guess a `Content-Range` header in between the two parts, use `strings` on the file or load in a text editor to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RFC 2616, Section 14.16](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.16.p.10):

> When an HTTP message includes the content of multiple ranges (for example, a response to a request for multiple non-overlapping ranges), these are transmitted as a multipart message. The multipart media type used for this purpose is "multipart/byteranges" as defined in Appendix 19.2. See Appendix 19.6.3 for a compatibility issue.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. But I not understand what should I do. response from the server really comes to describing the parts. They can be removed by passing the options you want? or the need to manually remove them upon receipt?

Comment: Either do not request multiple ranges, or you'll have to implement a proper parser for the multipart format.