# read multiple streams from a stream of a socket using java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, stream

Is there any way to read bytes randomly from a open socket stream? suppose i have opened a data stream in a website. traditional java classes giving me sequential access to the data. like a linked list. i want to randomly read data like reading data from random positions of an array. Suppose if the data size is 2048 KB, i want to read from 0 to 1204 KB with 1 thread and simultaneously want to use another thread to read data from 1205 to 2048 KB.

so the bottom line is i want to multi thread the  data reading process from a opened socket of a website. The process has to be like Internet Download Manager.
Please give me some tutorials link if its possible..

Comment: Short answer: no, because streams are not random-access.

Comment: If you're looking to write your own download manager, you should read up on HTTP Range Requests. Streams don't work the way you want.

Comment: Then is it possible to specify the byte location on the request?
so i will be able to use 2 or more threads to read data from different locations of the same stream one at a time. Will it give meany performance gain? @PhilippReichart

Answer (score 3):

Reading from random locations in a stream from a website using multiple threads is not possible.  The data comes down as a linear stream and there is no standard way to go to different positions in the stream in multiple threads.  Multiple threads *can* download different files a the same time however.

The HTTPD protocol does support the [`Range:` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) although I'm not sure how many web servers support the behavior -- Apache does for example.  If supported, the server should respond with the following header:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The client then can ask for a particular offset/length of the file:

```
Range: bytes=21010-47021
```

With this you *could* have multiple threads downloading from different ranges at the same time but I'm not sure how this will speed up the download unless you are requesting from multiple servers.  Most likely you will be running into disk and network limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The data from a socket arrives sequentially.  You'd have to use some fairly large buffering to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I thinkt what you are asking about is the http header

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Range: bytes=0-8999
```

Which will instruct the server to only send some of the file. You will then read the stream sequentially.

See also [How to assemble the file using the range header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981564/how-to-assemble-the-file-using-the-range-header)

edit: example

This seems to work

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URLConnection conn = new URL("http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/Contents-i386.gz")
            .openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Ranges","bytes");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=8000000-16000000");
    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
    List<String> serverranges = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Accept-Ranges");
    boolean ispartial = serverranges != null && serverranges.get(0).equals("bytes");
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int l ;
    System.out.println(ispartial);
    while((l=input.read(b, 0, b.length))>0){
        // if isPartial=true, we have server support. We received partial file.
        //do stuff with b,l
    }
}
```

It is important to note that not all servers support this, so check the isPartial variable. If it is false. The server does not support partial ranges and will give you the start of the file.

Comment: Actually i'm new to java and have no experience of networking.
So if you can give ma an example of what you have just said using java, it will be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read randomly over a socket. In principle, you have two options:

1. Read the whole data stream and put it an a buffer (a byte array for instance). Expose the buffer to each thread.
2. Read the whole data stream in each thread independently, having each thread ignore everything that should not read.